# Parsing html to some kind of wiki notation

Tags: c#, parsing, xpath, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Compacte energiebesparende COB LED-projector!</li>
    <li>
        GEEN aparte LED's: voorzien van een 100 W 2<sup>e</sup> generatie COB LED die perfect mengen van de kleuren verzekert en eruit ziet als een traditionele lamp!</li>
    <li>
        Twee verschillende hoeken voor de bundel:
        <ul>
            <li>
                70° breedhoek: perfect voor washing op korte afstand</li>
            <li>
                15° (geleverde lens): voor scherpe en goed gerichte bundelprojectie!</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        IR-afstandsbediening inbegrepen: geen moeilijke sturingen nodig. Perfect voor DJ's!</li>
    <li>
        Verschillende bedrijfsstanden:
        <ul>
            <li>
                Stand-alone met IR-afstandsbediening: automatisch/op de maat gesynchroniseerde kleurpatronen.</li>
            <li>
                Master/slave stand: er kunnen verschillende projectoren tegelijk worden gebruikt voor fantastische geprogrammeerde, met de muziek gesynchroniseerde lichtshows.</li>
            <li>
                DMX-gestuurd: verschillende kanaalstanden met programmakeuze en individuele RGB-regeling.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        Kan worden gebruikt met de populaire &nbsp;JB Systems LEDCON-02 Mk2 easy controller!</li>
    <li>
        Perfect voor mobiele toepassingen: zeer klein en een zeer laag stroomverbruik</li>
    <li>
        Neutrik<sup>®</sup> PowerCON<sup>®</sup> in-/uitgang met 16 A capaciteit voor het doorkoppelen van de stroom, voor gebruik met onze POWERCON/XLR COMBINATIEKABELS!</li>
    <li>
        Er zijn vele toepassingen mogelijk: Discotheken, DJ's, verhuurbedrijven, ...</li>
    <li>
        0-100% dimmen en ultrasnelle stroboscoopfunctie (geen extra stroboscopen nodig!)</li>
    <li>
        2x8-cijferig LED-scherm voor gemakkelijke navigatie van het menu</li>
    <li>
        Dubbele beugel: gemakkelijk om als vloerspot te gebruiken!</li>
</ul>
```

This has to be parsed to something like this:

```
- Compacte energiebesparende COB LED-projector!
-GEEN aparte LED's: voorzien van een 100 W 2e generatie COB LED die perfect mengen van de kleuren verzekert en eruit ziet als een traditionele lamp!
- Twee verschillende hoeken voor de bundel:
-- 70° breedhoek: perfect voor washing op korte afstand
-- 15° (geleverde lens): voor scherpe en goed gerichte bundelprojectie!
```

So I wrote this in C#:

```
            var unorderedLists = rootnode.SelectNodes("//ul//ul");
            if (unorderedLists != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode unorderedList in unorderedLists)
                {
                    string html = "";
                    unorderedList.InnerHtml = unorderedList.InnerHtml.Trim();
                    unorderedList.InnerHtml = unorderedList.InnerHtml.Replace("\n", "");
                    var listItems = unorderedList.SelectNodes("//li");
                    if (listItems != null)
                    {
                        foreach (HtmlNode listItem in listItems)
                        {
                            listItem.InnerHtml = listItem.InnerHtml.Trim();
                            listItem.InnerHtml = "-- " + listItem.InnerHtml + "\n";
                            html += listItem.InnerHtml;
                        }
                    }
                    unorderedList.InnerHtml = html;
                }
            }
            unorderedLists = rootnode.SelectNodes("//ul");
            if (unorderedLists != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode unorderedList in unorderedLists)
                {
                    string html = "";
                    unorderedList.InnerHtml = unorderedList.InnerHtml.Trim();
                    unorderedList.InnerHtml = unorderedList.InnerHtml.Replace("\n", "");
                    var listItems = unorderedList.SelectNodes("//li");
                    if (listItems != null)
                    {
                        foreach (HtmlNode listItem in listItems)
                        {
                            listItem.InnerHtml = listItem.InnerHtml.Trim();
                            listItem.InnerHtml = "-- " + listItem.InnerHtml + "\n";
                            html += listItem.InnerHtml;
                        }
                    }
                    unorderedList.InnerHtml = html;
                }
            }
```

Which basically first finds all ul's in a ul, removes the tags and adds the correct notation to it. But I get output like this:

```
-- -- -- Compacte energiebesparende COB LED-projector!
-- -- -- GEEN aparte LED's: voorzien van een 100 W 2e generatie COB LED die perfect mengen van de kleuren verzekert en eruit ziet als een traditionele lamp!
-- -- -- Twee verschillende hoeken voor de bundel:                      70° breedhoek: perfect voor washing op korte afstand                            15° (geleverde lens): voor scherpe en goed gerichte bundelprojectie!
-- 70° breedhoek: perfect voor washing op korte afstand
-- 15° (geleverde lens): voor scherpe en goed gerichte bun
```

After debugging I notice that the first part works correctly, after selecting the nested ul's I get 2 ul's back. Which is correct. Opening them in debugging I see the correct li's. But when it gets to the part where it selects the nodes inside the unordered list ( `var listItems = unorderedList.SelectNodes("//li");`) it contains 17(!) li's, namely all of the "parent" and "aunt/uncle" li's too..

And yes, I know, I could do it manually for this piece of html, but the doc is 400k lines long. So manually is not an option. This is just an extract that's buggy.

Comment: Why don't you have a look at https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com

Comment: Figured it out, my XPath was wrong.. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Lonefish Looks like you forgot the dot (`.`) at the beginning of the XPath to make it relative to current context element : `unorderedList.SelectNodes(".//li")`

Comment: Yeah, just figured it out myself, new to XPath and didn't know you had to "make" it relative. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Problem was with my XPath,

Apparently `//li` returns all `<li>` nodes, even if you call it on a childnode. The solution is to use `.//li`. The dot refers to the current node, on which you search for all li nodes.